# How to make the generic return type of a method dependend of the parameter type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a `convert` method, which takes a String and a class as arguments and constructs an object of the given class, which will be returned.

The usage should look like this

```
Something s = Converter.convert("...", Something.class)
```

Is it possible to express this with Java generics?

Comment: You *may* get some new insights out of [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/08/generic-object-converter.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be:

```
Class<T>
```

i.e.

```
public static <T> T convert(String source, Class<T> tClass)
```

Comment: @deamon: It's `Class` with uppercase, not `class`. Check Bozho's answer once again.

Comment: One small cap for me, one giant cap for the computer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
public class Main { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

   String s = convert(new String(), String.class);
}

private static <T>T convert(String string, Class<T> class1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return (T) new String();
} 
}
```

EDIT: in your method arguments its not class its Class
and while returning you should cast it to T ans return, like

```
     return (T) mapper.readValue(json, target);
```

Comment: In English, it's "you", not "u". Further, code blocks are to be indented with 4 spaces. You can select code and then press the `010101` button or `Ctrl+K` to get it indented. Also see message formatting rules in the right hand column.

Comment: @GK I formatted it with correct indentation, there was no need to replace my edit :)

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for your advise. I didnt know how to format. @Bozho thanks.